# where is the function inet_ntoa really defined?

Tags: c, network-programming

I see this following line in /usr/include/arpa/inet.h:

```
extern char *inet_ntoa (struct in_addr __in) __THROW;
```

but where is it really defined?

Comment: Depends on your OS. What is it?

Comment: Why the "*really*"? Header-files **never** define functions, but just declare them.

Answer (score 5):

The system headers merely declare the interface for invoking functions provided by the system. The actual implementation will be compiled into a (typically shared) library on the system. On some systems, the actual implementation is unavailable in source code form and  proprietary. Fortunately, on [GNU/Linux](https://github.com/heyc/glibc/blob/master/inet/inet_ntoa.c), [FreeBSD](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/libkern/inet_ntoa.c?v=DFBSD), and [Mac OS X](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/net.subproj/inet_ntoa.c), one can actually find the original implementation of inet_ntoa.

For GNU/Linux, it the implementation is part of the GNU C Library (glibc).

Answer (score 0):

It has been compiled and exists in Ws2_32.lib.

You could see what is a [Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computer_science%29)